# Round to significant digits *only* with decimal portion of number in R

Tags: r, rounding, significant-digits

The `signif()` function rounds values based on the specificed number of
significant digits in a given value. The function applies to all the
digits in the number, though, so numbers of different orders of
magnitude are rounded and truncated differently. For instance, with this
vector `x`…

```r
x <- c(100.1303421, 10.03421, 1.3421, 0.0003421)
lapply(x, signif, 2)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 100
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 10
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1.3
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 0.00034
```

… the first and second values are truncated to 100 and 10 and the
decimal values disappear, while the third and fourth values maintain
decimals (though different numbers). This is the expected output from
`signif()`—it rightfully takes into account all the digits when
determining significant.

Is it possible to ignore the integer part of each number and only format
the decimal part with a set number of significant digits? I'd like to be
able to return these values: `c(100.13, 10.034, 1.34, 0.00034)`; that
is, the complete integer preceding the `.`, followed by the significant
digits of the decimal portion of the number.

For now, I've created a function that separates values into integer and
fraction components and runs `signif()` only on the fraction component,
but this seems exceptionally hacky.

```r
signif_ignore_integer <- function(x, digits = 2) {
  as.integer(x) + signif(x - as.integer(x), digits)
}

lapply(x, signif_ignore_integer, 2)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 100.13
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 10.034
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1.34
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 0.00034
```

Is there a better, more recommended way (possibly with some fancy
`sprintf()` format) to round values to a given number of significant
digits while ignoring their integer components?

Comment: There may be a better way, but your approach doesn't seem unreasonable. But you can streamline it by using `floor` and taking advantage of vectorization to avoid `lapply`: `my_signif = function(x, digits) floor(x) + signif(x - floor(x), digits); my_signif(x,2)`

Comment: Oh excellent—it's reassuring to know that this isn't unreasonable.

Comment: I realized there's an even more streamlined approach which I've posted as an answer (and which @Ryan just posted in a (now-deleted) comment as well).

Comment: It appears that the pre-formatted numbers (`sprintf` and `formatC`) don't support what you are trying to do. Take a look at the text in the help file `?formatC` for the digits argument. "f" supports number of digits after the decimal, while others like "g" support display of significant digits.

Comment: Yeah, I've spent way too much time trying to figure out some `sprintf` incantation that would let me use "g" with only decimal numbers like "f", but it doesn't look possible.

Comment: Here is an sprint method, though it's not pretty: `temp <- sprintf("%.2g", x - trunc(x)); paste0(trunc(x), substr(temp, 2, nchar(temp)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way, but your general approach doesn't seem unreasonable. However, you can streamline it by using `floor`, taking advantage of vectorization to avoid `lapply`, and using the mod operator to return the fractional part of each number:

```
my_signif = function(x, digits) floor(x) + signif(x %% 1, digits)

my_signif(x, 2)
```

> ```
> [1] 100.13000  10.03400   1.34000   0.00034
> ```

Comment: I'm guessing speed probably isn't an issue here, but for some reason `trunc` is a little faster than `floor`.

Comment: It looks like `trunc()` breaks with negative numbers, though: `my_signif(-10.03421, 2)` = -9.03. Replacing it with `floor()` gives the correct result of -10.03